# Fluorine Preparation:How can this be explained on basis of Lewis Acid-Base Reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides

How can this be explained on basis of Lewis Acid-Base Reaction ?

$\ce{2 K2MnF6 + 4 SbF5 → 4 KSbF6 + 2 MnF3 + F2↑}$

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine#Industrial

[Google Books reference (click me)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eYMQXWU_UaUC&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=2%20K2MnF6%20%2B%204%20SbF5%20%E2%86%92%204%20KSbF6%20%2B%202%20MnF3%20%2B%20F2%E2%86%91&source=bl&ots=8GJuTLnTw9&sig=UdqZpxWj-N-zzolkeWwRCvptz-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-7m-kcnKAhWOG44KHROBAo0Q6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=2%20K2MnF6%20%2B%204%20SbF5%20%E2%86%92%204%20KSbF6%20%2B%202%20MnF3%20%2B%20F2%E2%86%91&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{2 K2MnF6 + 4 SbF5 → 4 KSbF6 + 2 MnF3 + F2↑}$

Occurs in two stages. First there is a (Lewis) acid-base reaction

$\ce{2 K2MnF6 + 4 SbF5 → 4 KSbF6 + 2 MnF4}$

where the Lewis acid $\ce{SbF5}$ accepts a lone pair from a fluorine in the manganese complex, and the adduct then falls apart to leave $\ce{MnF4}$. This is thermally unstable at ambient temperatures (Housecroft and Sharpe) and falls apart in the redox reaction

$\ce{2 MnF4 → 2MnF3 +F2}$

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a double Lewis acid-base reaction. One Lewis acid-base complex is broken down while another is formed.

The starting compound potassium hexafluoridomanganate(IV) or $\ce{K2[MnF6]}$, features a complex hexafluoridomanganate(IV) ion which is a Lewis acid-base adduct. Upon adding $\ce{[SbF5]}$, we suddenly have two Lewis acids — $\ce{[MnF4]}$ and $\ce{[SbF5]}$ — both competing for the Lewis bases $\ce{F-}$. It turns out that $\ce{[SbF5]}$ is the stronger Lewis acid, i.e. the acid-base equilibrium is shifted to the product side.

$$\ce{[MnF6]^2- + 2 [SbF5] <=>> [MnF4] + 2 [SbF6]-}\tag{1}$$

Thus, the more stable Lewis acid-base adduct has been formed. Manganese(IV) fluoride is not stable with respect to degradation, i.e. the redox decomposition to form manganese(III) fluoride and fluorine is favourable.

$$\ce{2 MnF4 -> 2 MnF3 + F2 ^}\tag{2}$$