# Production of fluorine gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, synthesis

I have to suggest a method in order to produce $\ce{F2}$. It also says that I should consult the redox potential values. I know that there is a way to produce fluoride which is:

$$\ce{K2[MnF6] + 2 SbF5 -> 2 K[SbF6] + MnF2 + F2}$$

I also know that it can be produced by the electrolysis of non-aqueous halides ($\ce{KF}$).

Why do I have to check the values of redox potential? I know that $\ce{F2}$ can't be produced by the electrolysis of aqueous solutions because it oxidizes water.

Is this method correct?

\begin{align}
\ce{2 K+ + 2 e- &-> 2 K} \\
\ce{2 F- &-> F2 + 2 e-} \\
\hline
\ce{2 K+ + 2 F- &-> F2 + 2 K}
\end{align}

Comment: RE:  "Is this method correct?" // You jumped to the ending without telling the story. How do you propose to get $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{F-}$? (I have real nice method in mind...)

Comment: Very related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44296/fluorine-preparationhow-can-this-be-explained-on-basis-of-lewis-acid-base-react

Comment: It is a Lewis acid-base reaction.

Comment: My question is not about the first reaction. Also, using KF helps increasing conductivity. For example, when we want to achieve industrial production of Cl2 we can use the electrolysis of melt NaCl. I assume that I have to consult the values of redox potential in order to decide who gets the electrons. But I can't figure out what I should use in order to produce F2.

Comment: I don't know if the production of fluorine gas has a similar method like the production of Cl2 which is: Cathode(-) : Na+  + e- → Na  and Anode(+) : 2Cl- → Cl2 + 2e-    and after electrolysis we get the Cl2. But I don't know that I will use for anode and cathode.